# CakePHP 1.3: acl_extras plugin

Tags: cakephp, acl

All,

As I am still using CakePHP 1.3 I am in need of using the acl_extras plugin for this version of Cake. Does anyone know where I can possibly find one? The one on GitHub https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras is for CakePHP 2.0.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On github nothing gets lost. you just need to switch to the 1.3 branch:

https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/tree/1.3